# show that the function $f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+t^2}$ satisfies Lipschitz condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

show that  $$f(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{1+t^2}$$ 
is defined $0<x<p, 0<t<N$ ( where N is positive integer ) Lipschitz condition with Lipschitz constant $N$

**Attempt**

consider $|f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)=|\frac{e^{-x_1}}{1+t^2}-\frac{e^{-x_2}}{1+t^2}|\\=|\frac{1}{1+t^2}(e^{-x_1}-e^{-x_2})|$

from here how to we procesed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac 1 {1+t^{2}} \leq 1$ and $|e^{-x}-e^{-y}| \leq |x-y|$ for $x,y \geq 0$. The second inequality follows by MVT.

Comment: ...Wow thank you sir ..your idea is really great.....